# How "dir" works with "puts" and "File::realdirpath()"

Tags: ruby

Please find the below code:

```
current_dir = Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir('C:\Documents and Settings\Peter\My Documents\userdata\Downloaded Files')
current_dir = Dir.pwd

Dir.entries(current_dir)[2..-1].each do |dir|

  puts dir
  puts "-------"
  Dir.entries(dir)[2..-1].each do |d|

    #file_loc_dir =
    #File.rename(d, dir.concat(d))
    puts File.realdirpath(d ,dir)
    #puts dir.concat(d)

  end
  puts "-------"
end
```

***Output:***

```
C:\Documents and Settings\peter\My Documents\userdata\Ruby\Scripts>FileNamere
naming.rb
D07141
-------
C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/Downloaded Files/D07141
/Water lilies.jpg
C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/Downloaded Files/D07141
/Winter.jpg
-------
D07141101
-------
C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/Downloaded Files/D07141
101/Water lilies.jpg
C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/Downloaded Files/D07141
101/Winter.jpg
```

***Confusion:***

While `puts dir` gives `D07141` and `D07141101`, `File.realdirpath(d ,dir)` gives the *expanded* directory name. Could you please clarify the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Returns the real (absolute) pathname of pathname in the actual
>   filesystem. The real pathname doesn’t contain symlinks or useless
>   dots.
>
> If dir_string is given, it is used as a base directory for
>   interpreting relative pathname instead of the current directory.
>
> The last component of the real pathname can be nonexistent.

(http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/File/realdirpath/class)

It is expanded because that is what the method does. You aren't calling `puts` on the dir inside of the `#entries` call, you are calling it on the return value of `File.realdirpath`, which, as discussed above, expands the passed in entry.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I am confused with `Dir` value:- When it is with `puts` giving `D07141`, but now inside `File.realdirpath` how `dir` expands to `C:/Documents and Settings/peter/My Documents/userdata/Downloaded Files/D07141` ? - this is the question of mine. I am not confused with the output of `File.realdirpath`

Comment: @TheMiddleMan it calls `expand_path` with the default as the current working directory, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path

Comment: @iain Okay! got now. That means `dir` object within the `File.realdirpath()` automatically calls the `File::expand_path()` method. Now that sounds good!